# JQuery not returning select box values if no element is selected

Tags: jquery

Not sure whats going on here, I must be missing something. I have two select boxes and users can move elements between them to select which data elements they would like to download, here is the screen grab:[image: Everything is groovy]

Everything works great EXCEPT when the user moves some elements back to the "Data Concepts" box leaving no elements in the "Selected Data" selected, as seen here:
[image: Not cool]

Here is the code that is grabbing the values from the "Selected Data" box:

```
var ExportSel = [];

$('#DataList2').each(function(){
ExportSel = $('#DataList2').val();
});
```

But this returns an empty array if nothing is selected regardless of the number of elements in the "Selected Data" box. Although when I inspect it in firebug, it shows the elements and values are present in the selector box.

Am I misunderstanding the .each function, the .val function or something even more fundamental?

A huge thanks in advance, always impressed with the stack community!

Comment: Why are you using `.each()` when there can only be one element matching the ID?

Comment: `.val()` returns an array of all the selected options in a multi-select. In your `Selected Data` column, there are elements present but they're not selected.

Comment: I thought .each iterated over all the elements in the select box '#Datalist2', then I used .val to send the option value to an array. Ahh, I'm misunderstanding the .val(). I though it was returning everything.

Comment: `$(selector).each()` iterates over all the elements matching the selector, not their descendants.

Comment: And even if `.each` did what you thought, you're overwriting the `ExportSel` variable each time through, you're not adding to the array.

Comment: try something like this .... `var ExportSel = $("#DataList2 option").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a `<select multiple>` element is an array of all the selected options. But you don't care whether the options in the `Selected Data` column are selected, you want an array of all of them. So you need to iterate over the options, getting their values.

```
var ExportSel = [];
$("#DataList2 option").each(function() {
    ExportSel.push(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for clarifying, it makes much more sense now (and it works)!